# How to fix this error: illegal address in cuda queue copy_from_device (integrator_intersect_closest integrator_queued_paths_array)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

My gpu is a gtx 2080 super and cpu is razen 3700X. I get this error illegal address in cuda queue copy_from_device (integrator_intersect_closest integrator_queued_paths_array) around 50 frames into my render. I am rendering my animation in cycles.

Comment: Try to reinstall or update your Cuda driver.

Comment: Thank you that seems to have done it got past the 50th frame

Comment: Update around over halfway through my render got the same problem

Comment: Im having the same issues for a couple of weeks and im baffled that no one is talking seriously about this issue. I get the exact same cuda error. It started by just the usual cuda illegal adress error. But no i have this long text aswell. I just installed Blender 3.0 days ago i i get this error again. So it might be Nvidia. I think il go try out a old driver and come later back here to let know if it helped.

Comment: I just ran into this same problem after upgrading to 3.5.1, and it seems related to SubSurf, somehow. I still haven't figured out the details, but an object that I have a subsurf modifier on causes crashes when I try to append it to another scene. When I open a copy of that scene with that same object in it, the subsurf has infinite geometry artifacts, and when I delete the subsurf and try to add a new subsurf to it, Blender crashes and then can't open that scene file anymore.

Comment: It might be related to the adaptive subsurf, but still not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had the same problem, getting the error messages:

> illegal address in cuda queue copy_from_device
> (integrator_intersect_closest integrator_queued_paths_array)

and

> illegal address in cuda queue copy_from_device
> (integrator_intersect_closest)

Reading through blender forums, I read that this error may happen if a ray of light does not remain within the scene but much rather travels to infinity. At some point it was suggested to add a bounding box to the scene to avoid this problem.[Blender Forum](https://developer.blender.org/T93046)

This is what made the error disappear when rendering my scene. I put the whole scene into a box (I'm sure there's better methods) to make sure the maximum path light can travel is limited. No crash so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have a GTX 1650ti Laptop GPU and a Core i7 8th Gen CPU, same thing happended to me during a 140 frame render. On the 97th frame, blender stopped rendering as I opened up a game application that requires GPU. Displaying the following message:

> illegal address in cuda queue copy_from_device (integrator_intersect_closest integrator_queued_paths_array)

Sometimes if you have an outdated Nvidia driver, update it then restart blender gets rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me moving some elements around (outside of the camera frame) each time this happened, solved the issue. Its definitely a "patch up" method but helped me finish these renders, then in other project files it didn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting "illegal address in CUDA queue copy_from_device (integrator_shade_surface integrator_sorted_paths_array prefix_sum)

I will try the bounding box method, but I will need to hold it out. It's a very simple seen with textured text and some svg graphics also textured.

I am posting this in case anyone else has a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling overclocking on my 2060 RTX via the Dragon Center seem to have worked (at the time of writing this)

[image: dragon center]